# How to obtain fine-grained Authorization with .NET

Tags: .net, security, roles

I want to obtain an authorization similar to MSCRM:

[image: CRM Roles]

In this rappresentation we see:

- Entity (Marketing List, Campaign)
- Allowed Operation (Create, Read, Write, Delete, Append, Append To, Assign, Share)
- Scope (User, Business Unit, Parent, Organization)

I have 2 Entities + 8 Allowed Operations + 4 Scopes.

I want to represent the same situation in a .NET Application. **The only way I see to obtain this is to create all the groups needed to express the various combinations**. In the example I need 2*8*4 = 64 groups handled in my code using methods in RoleProvider.

It seems a little bit strange for me. I'm missing some security concepts or creating 64 groups is the only way to express this level of configurability?

Thanks

Comment: What version?  Quite a few changes in Fx4

Comment: nope, I've decided a custom database solution and wrapping utility solution but I think it would be done better!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes you have to have 64 things to indicate their permissions, 64 groups no.

We use a similar model in an application that my company develops, but we have something like this.

User Permission Levels

- Level 1
- Level 2
- Level 3
- Level 4

App Domains (Different Chunks where people may need different permissions)

- Domain 1
- Domain 2
- Domain 3
- Domain 4

Then in the admin section a user gets assigned permissions as follow:

```
        Domain 1    Domain 2   Domain 3   Domain 4
User A   Level 1    Level 4    Level 3     Level 3
```

Then in the app we say

Domain 1 Security Code

```
If currentUser.Islevel1 Then
  YouCanDoIT();
Else
  WhyYouHereBro();
End
```

Basically you assign the user a permission level for a domain and have the Security permission check only the level for that domain. Let me know if you need actual implementation details.

Comment: I don't understand, your solution is a custom management or you are using .NET Security? My attempt is to use default .NET behaviors as much as possible

Comment: @Ricibald, It's kind of a hybrid. We set the current user and what not, and then when we look up the IsLevel1 (Which is an extension method) it calls some custom code.

Comment: Ok, but internally you have created "64 roles" in .NET?